# What is the purpose of componentClass prop in reactbootstrap

Tags: react-bootstrap

I read [react-bootstrap button doc](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#buttons-props) and there is `componentClass` prop that I can't understand. They explain it like "You can use a custom element type for this component".

What is the purpose of this prop? Any examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doc is right here. Basically when you create a `Button` component it will be rendered as `button` html element by default. 
In case when you want to have it wrapped inside "custom component", for example `<span>` you can use `componentClass` property to handle that for you.

Example:

```
  var Button = React.createClass({

    render() {
      return <h1 ref='button_node'>
      <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="success">Button</ReactBootstrap.Button>
      </h1>;
    }
  });  

  var CustomButton = React.createClass({

    render() {
      return <h1 ref='button_node'>
      <ReactBootstrap.Button componentClass="span" bsStyle="danger">Custom one</ReactBootstrap.Button>
      </h1>;
    }
  });  

  ReactDOM.render(<Button/>, document.getElementById('button')); 
  ReactDOM.render(<CustomButton/>, document.getElementById('custom-button'));
```

In this case `Button` will be rendered as default `button` element and `CustomButton` in `span`.